# Looking for a service/way to maintain dns server from c#

Tags: c#, azure, dns

I need to be able to from code to setup dns records. What options do I have?

The solution will be run on Windows Azure, so running a virtual machine with a DNS server and manage that from code is okay if thats possible. What other options do I have?

I am new to DNS administration and need to figure how how to best do this. Our task is simple, we will dynamicly deploy websites and would like to add dns records such .ourdomain.com or .sites.ourdomain.com  get created automatic when new sites are created. So a short intro to what to read up on is also welcome. I have a basic understanding of DNS and know what different records mean, but have always just manual maintained those for my own site in a web interface at some free service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run your own DNS server in Azure on a Virtual Machine.  Unfortunately, interacting with Windows Server DNS's service on an API level is tough.

One suggestion is to look into other DNS providers that offer API access.  Here's a link to Stackoverflow question that covers this subject: [Cloud DNS Service with API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449941/cloud-dns-service-with-api)

Another alternative to consider is to have a small reliable website that is hosted under the catch-all domain (.yourcompany.com) and would inspect the host headers and redirect based on those.  This is assuming that all of your domains are needed to host websites and not some other apps.  Using host-header inspection will eliminate the need to screw around with DNS and transfer the logic to your application's routing layer - which is usually much simpler to deal with.

HTH